# Asymptotic equivalence joint probability

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Suppose that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are random variables, not independent from each other.
In addition, we know that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{ P(A+B>x)}{P(A>x)}=1,$$
$$\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{P(C-B>y)}{P(C>y)}=1$$
For positive $x, y$, we clearly have $P(B>x, -B>y)=0.$

Let $\frac{x}{y} \to c>0$ as $x \to \infty$. Is this enough to prove,  $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{P(A+B>x, C-B>y)}{P(A>x, C>y)}=1?$$
Do we need more assumptions? How to approach such a problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "as $x, y \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$"?

Comment: I meant that $x$ and $y$ both go to $\infty$ when I write $x \to \infty$, in that way I dont need to write a double limit.